# Differentiate the product of some terms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I compute the following derivative,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_j} \prod_{i=1}^k (1+\lambda_i)e^{\lambda_i} \quad \text{for }\; 1\le j \le k
$$

for some positive integer $k$ which is not known? Note that it is simple to compute the derivative by hand, but I just wonder how such equations can be input in *Mathematica*.

**Edit:**
After halirutan's answer, I decided to update the question. What I understand from his answer is that: there is no simple straight forward way to express such an example. Now, my question is that: is it possible to add some rewriting rules to *Mathematica*'s built-in `D` and `Simplify` functions such that, running

```
Assuming[1<=j<=k&&j\[Element]Integers,
   Simplify[D[Product[(1 + l[i]) Exp[l[i]], {i, k}], l[j]]]
]
```

Returns the desired output:

$$
\frac{2+\lambda_i}{1+\lambda_i}\prod_{i=1}^k (1+\lambda_i)e^{\lambda_i}
$$

Comment: A smaller example of this kind would be to calculated the part. derivative of `Sum[l[i], {i, k}]` wrt some `l[j]`. To solve this you need to imagine the sum expanded and then you see that it's always 1. The step of imagination does not work in Mma because it needs to consider all possible cases.

Comment: Regarding your edit: No, this is not possible without substantially changing the system. `Simplify` does not `Hold` the expression to simplify. This means, your expression `D[Product[(1 + l[i]) Exp[l[i]], {i, k}], l[j]]` is first evaluated to 0 before `Simplify` can do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in my comment, the hard thing here is, that Mathematica cannot expand your `Product` for an unknown `k`. What you know is, that $1\leq j \leq k$ but I don't how I could help Mathematica, that it expands your Product with this knowledge. What we want to do is the following:

$$\prod_{i=1}^k (1+\lambda_i)e^{\lambda_i} \rightarrow \\\left(\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} (1+\lambda_i)e^{\lambda_i}\right) \cdot \left((1+\lambda_j)e^{\lambda_j}\right)\cdot \left(\prod_{i=j+1}^k (1+\lambda_i)e^{\lambda_i}\right)$$

Let's try to do this small part manually

```
expr = Product[(1 + l[i]) Exp[l[i]], {i, k}];
exprExpanded = expr /. Product[f_, {i_, k_}] :> 
  Product[f, {i, 1, j - 1}]*(f /. i :> j)*Product[f, {i, j + 1, k}]
```

$$e^{l[j]} (1+l[j]) \left(\prod _{i=1}^{-1+j} e^{l[i]} (1+l[i])\right) \prod _{i=1+j}^k e^{l[i]} (1+l[i])$$

In this form we can derive the expression with `D` because everything which depends on `l[j]` is extracted

```
dexpr = D[exprExpanded, l[j]]
```

$$e^{l[j]} \left(\prod _{i=1}^{-1+j} e^{l[i]} (1+l[i])\right) \prod _{i=1+j}^k e^{l[i]} (1+l[i])+e^{l[j]} (1+l[j]) \left(\prod _{i=1}^{-1+j} e^{l[i]} (1+l[i])\right) \prod _{i=1+j}^k e^{l[i]} (1+l[i])$$

This is the general analytic form of your derivative. Now you can check whether it is equivalent to calculated derivative when you insert special values for `j` and `k`

```
(dexpr /. {j :> 3, k :> 5}) == D[Product[(1 + l[i]) Exp[l[i]], {i, 5}], l[3]]
(*
 True
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice answer halirutan. I updated the question. Could you let me know your thoughts about it.

Comment: @Mohsen Have you seen the `TransformationFunctions` option for `Simplify`?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind modifying the behavior of built-in symbols, you could modify [`Product`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product) as follows:

```
Unprotect[Product];
D[Product[f_, iter_], p_, q__] ^:= D[D[Product[f, iter], p], q]
D[Product[f_, iter_], p_] ^:= With[{res = iD[Product[f, iter], p]},
    res /; res=!=$Failed
]
Protect[Product];

iD[Product[f_, iter_], {p_, n_Integer}] := If[ListQ[p],
    $Failed,
    Nest[D[#, p]&, iD[Product[f, iter], p], n-1]
]

iD[Product[f_, iter_], p_List] := $Failed
iD[Product[f_, iter_], p_] := Product[f, iter] D[Sum[Log[f], iter], p]
```

*(it is also possible to use [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) for [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) instead of [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for [`Product`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product), but I prefer the use of [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) to avoid slowing down [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D))*. Then, your requested simplification happens automatically:

```
Assuming[1<=j<=k && j∈Integers,
    Simplify @ D[Product[(1+l[i]) Exp[l[i]], {i,k}], l[j]]
] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{(l(j)+2) \prod _i^k e^{l(i)} (l(i)+1)}{l(j)+1}$