# Partial derivative of n-variables product

Tags: products, subscript

I am new to Mathematica. I would like to calculate the partial derivative of the product,
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}} y \prod _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^3=\frac{3}{x_j} y \prod_{i=1}^nx_i^3$, where $1 < j < n$,
and
$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} y \prod _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^3= \prod_{i=1}^nx_i^3$ .

I have try the code `D[Product[y*Subscript[x, i]^3, {i, 1, n}],Subscript[x,j]]` and [Carl Woll's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156311/73391), but get `0`. And the [halirutan's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11939/73391) works but not neat one with piecewise production.

How to use Mathematica 12.0 to calculate derivatives and get a nice and exact result?

Comment: One can start here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/how-to-differentiate-formally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiate the product of some terms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11936/differentiate-the-product-of-some-terms). In particular, check out my answer (which sadly has no votes).

Comment: I get `Product[y*Subscript[x, i]^3, {i, 1, n}]*Sum[(3*KroneckerDelta[i, j])/Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}]` in M12.0.1 using my answer. Have you tried from a fresh kernel? Also, it might work better if you use `x[i]` instead of `Subscript[x, i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowledge of `n,j` the expression cannot be evaluated.

For example

```
D[Product[Subscript[x, i]^3, {i, 1, 5}], Subscript[x, 3]]
```

evaluates as expected

Comment: How can I evaluate it without specifying j=3？